# Rules: how to create variable with PHP and $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER']

Tags: 7, rules, actions

I want to parse the query string off the HTTP_REFERRER and make that available as a variable for actions to use.

I feel like one of these options should let me do that, but I can't be sure...

[image]

The concept is simple

```
<?php 
  $parts = parse_url( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERRER'] );
  parse_str( $parts['query'], $q );
  // now set $q (or its elements) as the variable
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I just had to look harder and change my expectations a little.

1. Click `Add a Variable`
2. Select `text` (for my scenario)
3. In the `Value` field, you can then use php to echo out a value for a single variable

I was hoping to be able to create a variable with a type of 'object' (or similar) so that I could use the url values like `[url:param1]` or `[url:param2]`.

I have not found a way to do that - I just created a different variable for each of the two parameters I needed off the query string.